# How does Java evaluate multiple Condition in if?

Tags: java

Consider following Code

```
    boolean a = false;
    boolean b = false;
    boolean c = true;
    if( a && b | c) {
        System.out.println("Bitwise |");
    }

    if( a && b || c) {
        System.out.println("Short Circuit ||" );
    }
```

Above Code gives Result : **Short Circuit ||**

I don't understand how does java evaluate above condition ?

Comment: what above condition you are asking? there are two as far as I can see. It is not clear what is troubling you.

Comment: `|` has higher precedence than `&&`.